# How to enable hostname resolution (dns) for lxd containers from the lxd host?

Tags: domain-name-system, lxd

How to enable lxd hostname resolution from the lxd host?

After creating the below container:

```
>>> lxc launch ubuntu: container
Creating container
Starting container

>>> lxc list
+-----------------+---------+----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| container       | RUNNING | 10.240.38.157 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+-----------------+---------+----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
```

It can be reached using the IP address but not using the hostname:

```
>>> ping 10.240.38.157 -c 3
PING 10.240.38.157 (10.240.38.157) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.240.38.157: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
64 bytes from 10.240.38.157: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from 10.240.38.157: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms

--- 10.240.38.157 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2044ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.041/0.058/0.082/0.019 ms

>>> ping container
ping: unknown host container
```

How to enable the lxd containers to be reached by hostname from the lxd host?

Comment: Note that name resolution works from inside the containers by default.